# Puppeteer old Headless deprecation warning:

Tags: automation, puppeteer, headless, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

```
const bot = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require("fs");
const botConfiguration ={
headless:false, 
executablePath:"C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",
userDataDir: "C:/Users/bot/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/",
args: ['--profile-directory=Profile 28']
};
async function runBot() {
const chromeBrowser = await bot.launch(botConfiguration)
const chromeBrowserPage = await chromeBrowser.newPage()
await chromeBrowserPage.goto("https://www.google.com/")
};
runBot();
```

Puppeteer old Headless deprecation warning:

In the near future `headless: true` will default to the new Headless mode
for Chrome instead of the old Headless implementation. For more
information, please see https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/.
Consider opting in early by passing `headless: "new"` to `puppeteer.launch()`
If you encounter any bugs, please report them to https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/new/choose.

I do not want to see this error in my terminal ............

Puppeteer old Headless deprecation warning:

Comment: I'm confused--the error message tells you what to do to silence the warning (it's not an error). Did you try setting `headless: "new"` instead of `headless:false`?

Answer (score 7):

It is just a warning for users. The only way to make it disappear is putting headless:'new' option. If you dont care your headless option, just change yours with the offered one.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: 'new',
  // `headless: true` (default) enables old Headless;
  // `headless: 'new'` enables new Headless;
  // `headless: false` enables “headful” mode.
});
```